# Changing mode for (ng2-)codemirror in Angular 2

Tags: angular, codemirror

I managed to make `ng2-codemirror` editor work perfectly in my Angular 2 app, but there's one small detail that bugs me - I can't change its `mode` because it requires importing `.js` file which I am not able to accomplish. I need to import `script` from path `node_modules\codemirror\mode\clike\clike.js`, but it seems I don't know how to do it. I tried to import it in `index.html`:

```
<script src="node_modules/codemirror/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined

I'll simplify my code so it's easy to understand the problem:

**system.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      'ng2-codemirror': 'npm:ng2-codemirror',
      'codemirror': 'npm:codemirror'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': { main: './index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ng2-codemirror': { main: 'lib/Codemirror.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'codemirror': { main: 'lib/codemirror.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { myComponent } from './myComponent.cmp';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { ROUTING } from './browseClasses.routing';

import { myService } from './myService .service';

import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        ROUTING,
        CodemirrorModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [
        myComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        myService
    ]
})

export class BrowseClassesModule { }
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/my_component/myComponent.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    codeToDisplay: string;
    codeConfig = {
    lineNumbers: true,
    readOnly: true,
    mode: "text/x-java" <--- I can't make this work
}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.codeToDisplay = this.getCode();
    }

    getCode() {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="codeToDisplay">
    <codemirror [(ngModel)]="codeToDisplay" [config]="codeConfig"></codemirror>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ClassLoadingS1</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/codemirror/lib/clike.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" />

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <my-app>
    <div class="center-div">
      <img src="app/css/loading.gif">
    </div>
  </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you add it to your `index.html`?

Comment: @PierreDuc I tried to do it, but forgot to mention. Check my updated post.

Comment: Probably adding `lib/codemirror.js` to your `index.html` as well (above the `clike.js`) will help. But I'm not sure that's the right way to go

Comment: Yeah, I managed to import the script now, although my `mode` attribute still doesn't work. But that's another problem, thanks a lot @PierreDuc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I just managed to make it work, you need to do the following:

1. Add `<script src="node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>` to `index.html` (thanks a lot @PierreDuc)
2. Import `mode` you want to use in your component, in my case it was `clike` mode:

   `import 'codemirror/mode/clike/clike';`

Comment: Spent waaaay too much time on this, never thought adding the import!! I've added `../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js` AND `../node/modules/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.ts` to `.angular-cli.json`, and while codemirror was loaded succesfuly, code highlight didn't work until I added the import. Thanks!

Comment: You have no idea how much this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If using angular-cli you only need to add the file(s) to angluar-cli.json and do the import in your component.  No need to add the script to index.html